# Multidimensional Array insert into Mysql rows

Tags: mysql, arrays, insert, multidimensional-array

I have an Array (twodimensional) and i insert it into my database.

My Code:

```
$yourArr = $_POST;

$action = $yourArr['action'];
$mysql = $yourArr['mysql'];
$total = $yourArr['total'];
unset( $yourArr['action'] , $yourArr['mysql'] , $yourArr['total'] );

foreach ($yourArr as $k => $v) {
  list($type,$num) = explode('_item_',$k);
  $items[$num][$type] = $v;
$pnr= $items[$num][pnr];
$pkt= $items[$num][pkt];
$desc= $items[$num][desc];
$qty= $items[$num][qty];
$price= $items[$num][price];


$eintragen = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rechnungspositionen (artikelnummer, menge, artikel, beschreibung,preis) VALUES ('$pnr', '$qty', '$pkt', '$desc', '$price')");
}
```

I get 5 inserts in the Database but only the 5th have the informations i want. The firsts are incomplete.

Can someone help me?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Is this php? If so please add the php tag

Answer (score 0):

check if You have sent vars from browser in array (like
input name="some_name[]" ...

also You can check, what You get at any time by putting var_dump($your_var) in any place in script.

good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have your query and the 5 assignments above that *outside* of the foreach. Instead in a new loop which only executes once for every item instead of 5 times. Your indentation even suggests the same however your brackets do not.

Currently it is only assigning one value each time and executing a new query. After 5 times all the variables are assigned and the last inserted row finally has everything proper.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$items = array();

foreach($yourArr as $k => $v) {

    // check here if the variable is one you need
    list($type, $num) = explode('_item_', $k);
    $items[$num][$type] = $v;
}

foreach($items as $item) {

    $pnr   = mysql_real_escape_string($item['pnr']);
    $pkt   = mysql_real_escape_string($item['pkt']);
    $desc  = mysql_real_escape_string($item['desc']);
    $qty   = mysql_real_escape_string($item['qty']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($item['price']);

    $eintragen = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rechnungspositionen (artikelnummer, menge, artikel, beschreibung,preis) VALUES ('$pnr', '$qty', '$pkt', '$desc', '$price')");
}
```

Switching on your error level to E_ALL would have hinted in such a direction, among else:

- unquoted array-keys: if a constant of
  the same name exists your script will
  be unpredictable.
- unescaped variables: malformed values
  or even just containing a quote which
  needs to be there will fail your
  query or worse.
- naïve exploding: not each $_POST-key
  variable will contain the string
  *item* and your list will fail, including subsequent use of `$num`